# how could I configure servicestack to treat text/x-json like application/json

Tags: servicestack

do to some type of bug in microsoft's service bus clients must send my servers text/x-json as as application/json causes the servicebus to crash or not respond.  So I am looking to configure ServiceStack to treat accept : text/x-json and content-type : text/x-json the same as it would treat them when set to application/json?  I looked at ContentTypeFilter.Regiser but it's not clear which serializer options I need to set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the existing JSON ContentType in [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) but you can register a new ContentType with something like:

```
appHost.ContentTypeFilters.Register(ContentType.Json,
    (r, o, s) => JsonDataContractSerializer.Instance.SerializeToStream(o, s), 
    JsonDataContractDeserializer.Instance.DeserializeFromStream);
```

Note: this is the same API that the built-in [CsvFormat](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.EndPoints/Formats/CsvFormat.cs#L13) and [HtmlFormat](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.EndPoints/Formats/HtmlFormat.cs#L28) use.